# Nested Map, accesing inner map value

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

For example I have a map like this:

```
    map<string , map <int , int>> example;
```

and an iterator:

```
    map<string , map <int, int>>::iterator iter;
    string word;
```

And i want to access to the inner map :

```
  for(iter = example.begin();iter!=example.end;iter++){

       iter = Map.find(word);
       iter -> second // 
  }
```

What i should do to access the inner map just for example if iter->second ==4 -it's is  not correct , 
or can i do (iter->second)->second ??? can u give me an advise. i undestand that iterator is giving me a pair of (int,int) so i tryed to do another iterator map ::iterator i; and to assing iter->second = i, but it didin't help me to;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For complex types use `typedef` it will make your life much easier:

```
typedef std::map< int, int > Ints;
typedef std::map< std::string, Ints > String2Ints;

String2Ints example;
std::string word;

String2Ints::iterator it = example.find( word );
if( it != example.end() ) {
   Ints &innerMap = it->second;
   Ints::iterator innerit = innerMap.find( 4 );
   if( innerit != innerMap.end() ) 
       std::cout << "found value for word " << word << " 4 - " << innerit->second << std::endl;
}
```

Also your loop and find inside is incorrect, you should either iterate over map or search for value by `find()`, what you do in your code does not make any sense (technically infinite loop if word is found)

Comment: thank's for good describing, it was just an example if word not found i will just breake my cycle.

Answer (score 3):

iter->second is a map, so if you want to find something in it you need another find.
You can also use your iterator directly, without the for loop.
Ex:

```
map<string , map <int, int>>::iterator iter;
iter = example.find(word);

if (iter != example.end()){
   map<int, int>>::iterator innerIter;
   int key = 4;
   innerIter = iter->second.find(key);
   if (innerIter != iter->second.end()){
       (...)
   }
}
```